Should I Keep the Directive Selector Prefix in an Angular DDD Project?
I'm working on an Angular project that follows Domain-Driven Design (DDD) principles, and I've set up the following structure:
user-management
└── ui
    └── directives
        └── limitTextareaLines.directive.ts

As part of enforcing coding standards, my .eslintrc.json file includes the following rule for directive selectors:
"rules": {
    "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
        "error",
        {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "user-management-ui"
        }
    ]
}

This configuration requires that my directive selectors use the format: user-management-ui-myDirectiveName.
While I understand the intention behind using prefixes for clarity and organization, I find this particular prefixing approach to be somewhat cumbersome.
My question is: Should I remove the prefix rule from ESLint to simplify the directive naming, or is it better to keep it for consistency and adherence to best practices in a DDD context?
Thank you for your insights!
